# Why can't I search for *OWSINTG, *OWSUSER or *OWSDATE managed metadata columns?

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, crawled-property

I'm trying to select the following OOTB managed properties in a search for discussion threads:

- `DescendantRatingsCountOWSINTG`
- `DiscussionLastUpdatedOWSDATE`
- `LastReplyByOWSUSER`

My query looks like this: `https://sharepoint/_api/search/query?querytext='* ContentTypeID:0x012002*'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,DescendantRatingsCountOWSINTG,DiscussionLastUpdatedOWSDATE,LastReplyByOWSUSER'`

However the three properties are never returned in the result set. As an example I looked at the `LastReplyByUserOWSUSER` managed property which is mapped at the `ows_q_USER_LastReply` crawled property by default. I added the `ows_LastReplyBy` crawled property because maybe related to that. After a full crawl same results. All three properties are set as retrievable.

What is up with these properties? Why can't I select them and view them in the search results?

Note: On another SharePoint farm the same query works flawlessly, so I'm missing something. The result source is set to continous crawl, I ran the full crawl manually though.

Comment: Are the marked as "Retrieavable" in the search schema?

Comment: All three properties are set as retrievable. Also the search works, Log shows no particular errors.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't seem related to these particular mm-columns. I added a `TestProp` mapped to crawled property `Title` and it is also not returned when using it in `selectproperties`. This is weird - why are only certain columns returned? I also tried `bypassresulttypes=true`